# Strings of length $n$ enumerated by Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, computability

If $E$ is an enumerator and $n$ is a natural number, we define $\langle E,n \rangle$ to be all strings of length $n$ enumerated by $E$. Is $\langle E,n \rangle$ recognizable? Is it decidable?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: What does "language enumerated by E with length n" mean? What's the *length* of a language?

Comment: The OP probably meant all words with length $n$ generated bt the enumerator

Answer (score 0):

All finite languages are decidable.